# Make sure all values are used in drop downs

Tags: jquery

I have 4 `<select>` boxes with the same values:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

I wish to make sure each of these values are used in the dropdowns, with no duplicates.

I can not get my head around this. I have tried looping the select boxes and picking out the values, but I can not get it to work probably. Does anyone have a quick-n-easy solution to this?

Comment: Welcome on SO! You have forgotten to post any relevant code...

Comment: Yes, sorry - I was unable to provide any "relevant" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the unique value list then check the length with the original array.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

if ($.unique($('select').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); })).length === arr.length) {
   // OK
}
```

Comment: Lets say I added a another value "-1" (e.g. used for "Choose value"), can this still be used?

Comment: Got it to work by checking for -1 before returning the .val(). Used "return;" - is this OK? ;-)

Comment: @xdazz could you explain this a bit, it appears https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ only works for DOM elements. The result of the map of selects returns an array of numbers. Also see OP's follow up question which confirms the unique issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356314/ensure-all-values-are-used

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem

**HTML**

```
<select id="sselect"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var a = [1,2,2,3,4,5];
var duplicates = a;
var result = [];
$(function() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       var item = a[i];
    for ( var c = 0; c < duplicates.length; c++) {
          if (jQuery.inArray(item, result) == -1) {
         result.push(item);
        }
    }
}
});

for ( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
 $('#sselect').append($('<option>', { 
        value: result[i],
        text : result[i] 
    }));
}
```

[Live example of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/rajke88/jevCM/5/)