# Ensure all values are used

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make sure that all values, except one, is used in my drop downs - but there is an error, where its possible to cheat on it. And I am not sure why.

You can try it on: http://jsfiddle.net/BSxXk/2/ and use the values: `4 2 3 4` - This should produce an error since `1` is not used. I am using Firefox on Windows.

HTML:

```
<select name="answer" class="question-answer">
    <option value="-1">Choose value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="answer" class="question-answer">
    <option value="-1">Choose value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="answer" class="question-answer">
    <option value="-1">Choose value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select name="answer" class="question-answer">
    <option value="-1">Choose value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div id="result">d</div>

<button id="submit">Test</button>
```

JQuery:

```
var valid_values = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$("#submit").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = $.unique($('select.question-answer').map(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value === "-1") {
            return;
        }
        return value;
    }));
    if(values.length === valid_values.length) {
       $("#result").html("Valid");
    } else {
        $("#result").html("All values (1-4) should be used in answering the question.");
    }
});
```

Screenshot of error. 1 is not used, but says valid:

[image]

*Please note this is a follow-up of my previous question: [Make sure all values are used in drop downs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353848/make-sure-all-values-are-used-in-drop-downs)*

Comment: Your selects should have different names. Also, your fiddle has a typo `$("#subumit")`

Comment: Here is a correct fiddle with the posted code http://jsfiddle.net/BSxXk/2/ and it works fine

Comment: I use the same name for getting an array of results in a POST. I got 4 x <select> of 15 questions.

Comment: I got not valid upon your choices: 4-3-4-1 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick question, code in the fiddle does not match code posted. The fiddle works fine with the posted code

http://jsfiddle.net/BSxXk/2/

```
var valid_values = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$("#submit").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = $.unique($('select.question-answer').map(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value === "-1") {
            return;
        }
        return value;
    }));
    if(values.length === valid_values.length) {
       $("#result").html("Valid");
    } else {
        $("#result").html("All values (1-4) should be used in answering the question.");
    }
});
```

UPDATE

using jquery 1.10.1 works for me http://jsfiddle.net/BSxXk/5/
using anything above, does not work for me

I still think the use of unique is incorrect here, because $.unique only works on DOM elements https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ the map function on the question-answer only returns numbers so it makes perfect sense that unique does not work

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/BSxXk/2/ and pick values 4, 2, 3, 4 and click Test. This produce "valid", while its not - 1 is not used.

Comment: @meep How do you get this result? Works as expected for me

Comment: well then it looks like your last question's answer is incorrect then

Comment: @A.Wolff which browser are you using? I get valid with OP's input which should be invalid, using FF on mac

Comment: chrome win7 on my side

Comment: I'm using Firefox on Windows. Odd. Also see screenshot in question

Comment: I am guessing the issue is at unique, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246758/how-to-get-unique-values-in-a-array perhaps you should find unique in the values array

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: The link I provided already has examples, also see my update in my answer

Comment: Using the examples in the post, it seems to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/ciwaq/1/edit

```
$('button').click(function(){

  var values = ['1','2','3','4'];
  var selectValues = [];

  $('select').each(function(){
    selectValues.push($(this).val());
  });

  if($(values).not($(values).not(selectValues).get()).get().length !== values.length) {
     $('#result').html('All values are not used');
  }
  else {
    $('#result').html('All values ARE USED :)');
  }

});
```